# Setting .NET version in IIS application pool using WIX does not work

Tags: .net, iis-7, wix, wix3.5

```
<!-- Custom action to set the .NET version -->
<CustomAction Id="SetNetVersion_Cmd" Property="SetNetVersion"  Execute="immediate" Return="check" Value="$(var.SetNetVersionCmd)" />
<CustomAction Id="SetNetVersion" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no"/>

<!-- Run the action -->
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='SetNetVersion_Cmd' After='InstallFinalize' />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Here is what the msi log shows:

```
Action 22:02:57: SetNetVersion_Cmd. 
Action start 22:02:57: SetNetVersion_Cmd.
MSI (s) (44:9C) [22:02:57:533]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SetNetVersion property. Its value is '&quot;C:\Windows\\system32\inetsrv\appcmd&quot; set config -section:applicationPools -[name=&quot;PoolName&quot;].managedRuntimeVersion:v4.0'.
Action ended 22:02:57: SetNetVersion_Cmd. Return value 1.
```

The pool does exist but its.NET version is not changed.  What am I doing wrong?

The SetNetVersionCmd is:

```
'&quot;[WindowsFolder]\system32\inetsrv\appcmd&quot; set config -section:applicationPools -[\[]name=&quot;PoolName&quot;[\]].managedRuntimeVersion:v4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do this (still using AppCmd) is like so:

```
AppCmd Set AppPool "PoolName" /managedRuntimeVersion:v4.0
```

You should be able to reuse all the rest of your WiX code, just changing the value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but someone might find this useful and this place is a gold mine...

Still using Wix 3.5 personally, and the [manual](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/iis_xsd_webapppool.htm) states that we can set the `ManagedRuntimeVersion` when creating an application pool, however the documentation is for version 3.6...  Looking in my local help file the `ManagedRuntimeVersion` is not supported.